# Crossdomain in analytics add hits to the property?

Tags: google-analytics

When I have domains with CrossDomain the number of hits that the first site generates, are they added to the second domain or does each property register its hits independently?

Answer (score 0):

Each property in GA receives and process the hits independently.

**Exception** is a ***Rollup property***, where you can club two or more properties to have a holistic view of the data. This feature is only available in GA 360 [premium version].

Cross Domain is used for session unification, which makes it possible for Analytics to see sessions on two related sites as a single session.